# Como comparar el contenido de 2 variables Itextsharp.Image

Tags: c#, imagen, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo este código que funciona muy bien:

```
doc.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(CapturaBitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
doc.Add(pic);
doc.Close();
```

El problema es que no sé como puedo comparar el contenido de las dos variables iTextSharp.text.Image.
Por ejemplo teniendo una en pic y otra en pic2, con un simple "if (pic==pic2)" no va.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías pasarlo a un arreglo de bytes y comparar ambas secuencias. Si subes la misma imagen, la secuencia es la misma. Saludos. PD: Lectura sugerida https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como se te indicó en los comentarios, una manera de hacerlo es comparando los `byte`, además para esto puedes usar [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-8.0), que compara si 2 listas son iguales

```
if (pic.RawData.SequenceEqual(OtroPIc.RawData))
{
    Console.WriteLine("SON IGUALES");
}
```